# Authenticate oauth server using socialite

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle

We are using an internal oauth server running on localhost. How can we  authenticate it using Socialite and also disable the self signed certificate verification for testing?

error shows:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

Comment: Please refer to this thread [ssl_issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/37017)

Answer (score 0):

Please only do this on your dev machine!

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Works on both Linux and Windows.